# Double quotations in imported CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV like this for example:

```
ACCOUNT:STATUS:FIRST_NAME:LAST_NAME
12345:1:My "Problematic" Name:Last Name
```

If I use CSV.foreach I get message:
Illegal quoting in line 2

How can I handle this correctly and still preserve quotation marks in the string that I read?

My current code:

```
CSV.foreach("accounts_data.csv", { :col_sep => ':', headers: true } ) do |account|
end
```

Comment: For CSV to eat your line, it should be this: `12345:1:"My ""Problematic"" Name":Last Name`. If your file is not too big, you can do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the options to specify `col_sep` as your file uses colon(`:`) as separator, and `quote_char` to single quote just to get around double quote issue.

```
CSV.foreach("/path/to/file", {quote_char: "'", col_sep: ":"}) do |row|
  p row
end
```

Output:

```
["ACCOUNT", "STATUS", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME"]
["12345", "1", "My \"Problematic\" Name", "Last Name"]
```